# MassTransit and Quartz.net - How to populate lots of scheduled jobs

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net, masstransit, quartz

I have been looking at using MassTransit's Quartz.Net (using AdoJobStore) implementation to schedule messages send/publish for future and all of this works fairly smoothly.

The bit where I am stuck is, as a part of the production deployment, I need to set up a lot of "Scheduled Messages" to be issued at various times during the next year odd.

Is there a mechanism available to pre-populate the Quartz SQL store with Triggers/Jobs externally ?

Comment: Nothing out of the box will do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured a way to do this; posting here, so it might help others if needed.

The Quartz SQL DB is nothing but a simple data serialised into objects. 
e.g. varbinary for JOB_DATA and ticks in for time. Other values are fairly simple.

I ended up created a sample app to setup some schedules and then reversed the database later to figure.

It was all quite simple in the end, and now I have splain SQL insert script which inserts the schedules as a part of the CD pipeline.

Comment: Can you provide a sample with a minimum code to configure this setting?